# Django preview, TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I'm trying to make a Preview function. I'm reading this blog, [Django Admin Preview](http://latherrinserepeat.org/2008/7/28/stupid-simple-django-admin-previews/), but now I have the following error and I don't know what it means.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "/home/user/webapps/django/lib/python2.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm lost..

Edit:

Thanks guys/gals, here is my view.py and url.py:

```
    from diligencia.diligencias.views import preview

    url(r'^admin/diligencias/diligencia/(?P<object_id>\d+)/preview/$','preview'),
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),

    from diligencia.diligencias.models import Diligencia

    @staff_member_required
    def preview(request, object_id):
        return object_detail(request, object_id=object_id,queryset=Diligencia.objects.all(), template_object_name = 'diligencia_detail.html', )
```

Comment: More info about this would be helpful.
Which is your urls.py and views content? Could you think of something relevant that could cause the exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature for the `url` function within a urlconf is like this:

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
```

You are using positional parameters only, but are passing only regex, view and name. So Python thinks your third parameter is the `kwargs` dictionary, not the name.

Instead, do this:

```
url(r'^admin/diligencias/diligencia/(?P<object_id>\d+)/preview/$', name='preview'),
```

to pass the name as a kwarg so that Python recognises it properly.

Comment: Daniel Thanks, with a litter change is working: 
url(r'^admin/diligencias/diligencia/(?P<object_id>\d+)/preview/$', preview, name='preview'),

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your view isn't a function. Make sure the argument in your `urls.py` is a function that takes one parameter. Like :

```
import default

url(r'^s(?:ite)?/search$', default.search, name="search"),
```

And then you have in default.py

```
def search(request) :
    # do stuff
```